# how does twitter login button has height of 44 pixels

Tags: html, css

The height of the **Log In** button of twitter is 44px. https://mobile.twitter.com/login/error?redirect_after_login=%2F.

But there is no hardcoded value present in the css file. How does it take the pixel value as 44px or height.

Answer (score 3):

The height is not hardcoded, it is a result of border, padding and line height as seen in Firefox's box model view:

[image]

1px border top + 13px padding top + 17px line height + 12px padding bottom + 1px border bottom = total height of 44px

Comment: *high five* for this answer!! +1

Answer (score -1):

There is a "hardcoded" value; it's just not in px.

```
media="screen"
.w-button-common input, a.w-button-common:link input, a.w-button-common:active input, a.w-button-common:visited input {
line-height: 2em;
```

Comment: Yes, which gives the button a defined height, instead of its browser-default height.

Comment: Well, it can effect the height, of course. But so can a bunch of other factors as David's answer shows.